# angular | when I use 2 ngIf, how to read property of child component?

Tags: angular, error-handling, properties, angular-ng-if

ex) post_no=1, click the EDIT button.

An error occurs.

error: Can not read property 'edit' of undefined.

```
...
<app-editor *ngIf="!post_no" #editor_save></app-editor>
<app-editor *ngIf="post_no" #editor_edit></app-editor>
...
<div *ngIf="post_no; else notEdit">
    <button class="post-save-btn" (click)="editor_edit.edit()">EDIT</button>
  </div>
  <ng-template #notEdit>
    <button class="post-save-btn" (click)="editor_save.save()">SAVE</button>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

Using two ngIf seems to cause an property error. (editor_edit.edit())

Is there a good solution?

Other ways that do not use two ngIfs is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use hidden attribute, It will help to keep DOM present.

```
<app-editor [hidden]="post_no" #editor_save></app-editor>
<app-editor [hidden]="!post_no" #editor_edit></app-editor>
...
<div *ngIf="post_no; else notEdit">
    <button class="post-save-btn" (click)="editor_edit.edit()">EDIT</button>
  </div>
  <ng-template #notEdit>
    <button class="post-save-btn" (click)="editor_save.save()">SAVE</button>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

here's the  [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rq4un1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demo.

Comment: Thank you. But This method produces the same error.

Comment: I have updated my answer.. now try with latest solution

Comment: I tried applying [hidden] but the same error occurs.

Comment: stackblitz demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rq4un1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I think I got an error elsewhere in my source code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*NgIf removes the component from the DOM. So you can't access the component like you did.

As an alternative you can use [hidden] atribute, which uses the "display: none" css property.